# Would a "critique my philosophical view" Stack Exchange be a welcome idea?

Tags: discussion

(Apologies in advance if this isn't the correct place to put this, but I don't want to "jump the gun" and post to Area 51. I'd rather hear people's thoughts.)

I see a lot of questions asked and subsequently closed because they have an argumentative tone, or where the question is basically "this is my view, argue against it". These questions are rightfully closed, since they're not a good fit for *this* SE site. Do you folks think a Stack Exchange site where these kinds of questions are acceptable would be a good idea?

I have something sort of like the Code Review Stack Exchange in mind, except for philosophy. I have philosophical views (as do most of you, I'm guessing...) but I am not a professional philosopher, nor am I a student. As such, I don't really have anywhere to put my positions out there so I can refine them, and have them criticized at a higher level than random internet forums where responses often aren't very good (or at least sometimes devolve into silly debates about semantics and terminology). It'd be nice to be able to assume the site's audience has at least basic familiarity with philosophy and philosophical terminology.

I think it'd be neat to have a site where one could go to, post one's position, present arguments, and ask for criticism and feedback. Do you think a "criticize my philosophical view" type site would be a good idea?

Comment: I can see why SE doesn't like the sort of question you're describing but would agree it's a pity they cannot be asked.

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah, the more I think about it the more I understand why it doesn't seem right for SE. Such a hypothetical SE would probably be chaos, since there might not be any principled way to separate "good" questions from bad" questions. And the questions might be too peculiar to the asker's interest to be of much value to a wider audience. But a pity indeed, since lots of users at Philosophy SE are very knowledgeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it would not. SE team has been unwilling to approve proposals of the types

- "like Code Review but for ..."
- "like Software/Hardware Recommendations but for ..."

From the comments in [On proposals soliciting reviews, recommendations, comparisons, etc](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/on-proposals-soliciting-reviews-recommendations-comparisons-etc)

> what differentiates a site like codereview from a site like my proposal (Writing Review) ? – Adi219
>
> You can replace the word reviews for recommendations and the post above is equally applicable. Such questions pose the same type of problem; there is no problem statement to be solved definitively; no correct answer — just a broad premise tossed out for general input and feedback by whomever wishes to chime in. Nothing anyone says is inherent wrong or even most valid. SE is about vetting information. These types of open discussions do not work well in our Q&A format. That is why such questions are not accepted by the Writers Stack Exchange site set up to host this subject. – Robert Cartaino♦
>
> Code review was created in 2011, and performing a peer code review of best practices is nothing like asking how this death scene can be more emotional. Writing and other types of reviews has been proposed many many times and they never went anywhere. In the meantime, we’ve seen a lot of proposals and created a few sites soliciting these types of broad discussions and collaborations. It just was not a good fit for how our Q&A works, so we decided to no longer accept proposals trying to expand on that premise. – Robert Cartaino♦

Comment: Thank you. Well... that's pretty definitive I guess. Though I don't necessarily agree with Robert Cartaino's reasons. 1) There are flourishing SEs that ask general open-ended advice (workplace, world building, maybe academia). 2) Part of code review is subjective. 3) And even if open-ended SEs were disallowed, in the case of philosophy just because it's difficult to come to universal agreement it doesn't mean it (standards of good argument) is subjective, or that there's no right/wrong answers. There are objective standards to criticize an argument; it's part of how philosophy progresses.